# New custom content type: place image above body

Tags: theming

I would like to create a content type in which an image is inserted after the title and before the body. When I add an image to the image field, that image is placed after the body...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Drupal 7, you can change the placement of the image from within the interface by navigating to Structures-> Content Types-> *Name of your content type* and then clicking *Manage Display*.  Drag the image above the body to show it first.

Comment: Yes, and if you want more feature with displaying the image or node, user display suit module.

Comment: Display Suite - http://drupal.org/project/ds